# ReferenceError: require is not defined for rollup bundle js

Tags: javascript, three.js, rollup, rollupjs

So, I have been using rollup to bundle my js files, created for usage with three js. What I thought of is to minimize and bundle the three js files using rollup js.
I used npm and installed three and rollup using the command `npm install rollup three`.
The index.js file as created is:

```
import { Scene, PerspectiveCamera, WebGLRenderer } from 'three'

const scene = new Scene()
const camera = new PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10)
camera.position.z = 1

geometry = new BoxGeometry( 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 )
material = new MeshNormalMaterial()

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material )
const basic = basicScene()
scene.add( mesh )

const renderer = new WebGLRenderer({antialias: true})
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight )

document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement )

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)

  mesh.rotation.x += 0.01
  mesh.rotation.y += 0.01

  renderer.render( scene, camera )
}

animate()
```

The rollup config as used is `rollup.config.js`:

```
export default [{
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: {
    file: 'dist/bundle.js',
    format: 'cjs'
  }
}]
```

The final bundle.js file as generated after running `rollup --config` is:

```
'use strict';var three=require('three');const scene = new three.Scene();
const camera = new three.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10);
camera.position.z = 1;

geometry = new BoxGeometry( 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 );
material = new MeshNormalMaterial();

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
const basic = basicScene();
scene.add( mesh );

const renderer = new three.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
  mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;

  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

animate();
```

I have the following doubts with the given bundle.js file that is generated:
1. The bundle js as created uses `require`, which results in `ReferenceError: require is not defined for rollup`
2. Secondly, not sure why the bundled version is not really the complete minified version of the produced js file?

Great, if some could suggest the probable issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a minimal sample project if you use the `npm` version of `three.js` and build your project via `rollup`. It demonstrates all the bits which are necessary for a proper setup:

https://github.com/Mugen87/three-jsm

A few comments to your question:

- It seems you are not importing all classes from the `three` package. For example `BoxGeometry` or `MeshNormalMaterial` are missing.
- Besides, you are referring to the `Mesh` class over the `THREE` namespace which is obviously wrong.
- When importing `npm` packages, rollup requires the usage of [@rollup/plugin-node-resolve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-node-resolve).
- Minifying does not happen automatically. You need to use a separate plugin for this e.g. [rollup-plugin-terser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-terser).

Except for the last point, the mentioned sample project implements all above steps which are necessary for a proper build.